# Linking Stylesheets and Javascript in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

thanks for taking the time to look at my question.
I've been diving into Jquery mobile and trying to figure out everything it has to offer.
However, going off their site, i'm using their servers to host the javascript and css files that are provided off the quick start guide.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

I downloaded all the style sheets and javascript files from their site and have been having a hard time trying to figure out how to link them right and which ones to link (there's a total of 8 files and I can't seem to figure out how to get the right stylesheets to work. I hope I have provided enough information for some help! I appreciate any help that I can get on this question.

Comment: You want to use the same files as the ones listed in your question. `jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css`/`jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js`. The rest of the CSS files are so you can do tricky customization to the themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download and link the exact files that you're using (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js and the jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css  -- the compressed, gzipped with default theme)

Answer (score 0):

try `type` attribute:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```